# Ajax not posting to div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Everything in my script so far seems to work perfect. But the data inserted and retrieved through Json is not being inserted to my div. Can anyone with a keen eye see any issues.

```
<div id="commentaddid"></div>
```

AJAX

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#mycommentform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var streamidcontent = $(this).children('#streamidcontent').val();
    var content = $(this).children('#content').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comment_add.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { streamidcontent: streamidcontent, content: content}, 
    success: function(data){  
    $('#commentaddid').append('<div class="stream_comment">"+content+"</div>');
    }
    });
    return false
    });
    });
    </script>
```

MAIN STATUS AJAX I worked from.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var content = $("#toid").val();
var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg }, 
success: function(response){ 
 $("#newmsg").val(""); 
$("#homestatusid").html("<div id='divider-"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div class='userinfo'><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div class'delete' style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+response['streamitem_id']+"');\">X</div><a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'>"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"</a><span class='subtleLink'> said</span><br/><a class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>"+response['streamitem_timestamp']+"</a><hr>"+newmsg+"<div style='height:20px;' class='post_contextoptions'><div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\">Write a comment...</a></div><div id='streamlike'><a title='Like "+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"s status' id='likecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Like</a></div><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><a title='See who likes "+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"s status' href='include/likes.php?streamitem_id="+response['streamitem_id']+"' /></a></div></div></form></div><div id='streamdislike'><a id='dislikecontext_"+response['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Dislike</a></div><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div></form><div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div id='comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left><div class='stream_comment_inputarea'><input id='addcomment' type='text' name='content' style='width:100%;' class='input_comment' placeholder='Write a comment...'  onkeyup='growcommentinput(this);' autocomplete='off' onkeypress=\"if(event.keyCode==13){addcomment("+response['streamitem_id']+",this.value,'comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"',"+response['id']+",'"+response['first']+" "+ response['middle']+" "+response['last']+"');this.value='';}\"><br/></div></div>");
}
});
return false
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's usually *either* a php *or* a javascript problem. please next time verify that the PHP part is working correctly, so you don't have to post it.

Comment: ...do, however, post a sample JSON that the PHP script produces. This can be useful in debugging some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: maybe you do not want to `.append` to the `div` but to replace the `div`'s contents).

This code is wrong - you mismatched single and double quotes:

```
$('#commentaddid').append('<div class="stream_comment">"+content+"</div>');
```

Should be:

```
$('#commentaddid').append('<div class="stream_comment">'+content+'</div>');
```

...and actually, it should be more than that.

The value of `data` returned by JSON is a complex object which you ought to format (and it would be prudent in the PHP to issue a `Content-Type` for JSON too):

content = "**" + data.name + "** commented: " + ...

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching the data as `data`, but you are appending it as `content` (which is in fact the data you are sending). Change your code to

```
$('#commentaddid').append('<div class="stream_comment">'+data+'</div>');
```

Comment: And by the way, are you sure that you want to append the raw JSON as it is, or should you fiddle around with it, like creating some HTML elements with the JSON data before appending it?

Comment: Its for user comments, added to a main post. And the comments should go upwards and show the last comment above the input area. Non of these answer are working. I've tried most of them.

Comment: It is not supposed to work. You are just trying to append JSON data to the `div`, while in reality, you should take the data from the JSON array, construct HTML elements, like `'<p>'+data.first+'</p>'` and then append it.

Comment: I do realize that. I've updated the question with what I built for the main status. I'm aware how to do many things. Just seems to be not this time around.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#commentaddid').append('<div class="stream_comment">'+data.content+'</div>');
```